# Sorting indices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `I1`. I want to arrange the indices in order of increasing `j`. For example, in `[0, 1]`, `i=0,j=1`. But I am getting an error. The expected output is attached.

```py
import numpy as np

I1=np.array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 4],
        [6, 7]],

        [[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 7]]])  

order1 = I1[0,:, 1].argsort()
I10 =np.array([I1[0][order1]])
print("I10 =",[I10])
```

The error is

```
in <module>
order1 = I1[0,:, 1].argsort()

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

The expected output is:

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 7],
        [6, 7]],
       
        [[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 7]]])
```

Comment: The array in your example is a ragged shape. It's not clear which array you are talking about that has a shape of `(2,)`. An array of that shape would look like `np.array([1, 2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `key` parameter of `sorted()` Python built-in function:

```
import numpy as np

I1=np.array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 4],
        [6, 7]],
                [[0, 1],
                  [0, 3],
                  [1, 2],
                  [1, 4],
                  [2, 5],
                  [3, 4],
                  [3, 6],
                  [4, 7]]])  
I1 = np.array([sorted(i, key = lambda x : x[1]) for i in I1])
print(I1)
```

**Output:**

```
[list([[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4], [5, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [6, 7]])
 list([[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7]])]
```